# How can i find the moderated number of comments on the page/component

Tags: tridion, ugc

I am getting the number of comments value from the Item Statistics field's numberOfComments, But its return total number of comments.

Could any one please help me, how can i find only moderated number of comments in UGC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK currently there is no way to find it directly but you may allow only moderated comments and then count them like

```
   <ugc:ForEachComment runat="server">
    <% HttpContext.Current.Items["Count"] = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Items["Count"]) + 1; %>
            </ugc:ForEachComment>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Its working, but its should have some property variable to find the Number of moderated comments